# AngularJs: how to apply Form validation on dynamic element created by directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, angular-formly

In our form elements are created dynamically using ng-repeat.
Storing form values in $scope.answers.[attribute name].

In the same way I want to apply validation on change as form submit.
but unable to call validation on dynamic elements.

my html element (index.html)

```
<div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'text'" >
                        <text-control-dir data-que-obj="que.QuestionData" ></text-control-dir>  
                        {{answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName]}}
                        <span ng-show="DTOstep1.answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName].$touched && DTOstep1.answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName].$invalid">The name is required.</span>
                    </div>
```

(controlDirectives.js) directive have html for form controls. 
Refer this plunker for full code.
https://plnkr.co/edit/GA74YHNFxFb0ARg16Sjj?p=preview

Comment: You should use `ngForm` directive.

Comment: I am stuck to pass dynamic name here <span ng-show="DTOstep1.answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName].$touched && DTOstep1.answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName].$invalid">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to use `ngModel` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel. Otherwise it won't register any validation error in you form. Furthermore you you wont't need `elemen.on('change')` just use `ngModel` directive. Finally add `novalidate` attribute into you form element if you're using your own validation messages.

> ngModel is responsible for:
>
> - Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as input,
>     textarea or select require.
> - Providing validation behavior (i.e.
>     required, number, email, url).
> - Keeping the state of the control
>     (valid/invalid, dirty/pristine, touched/untouched, validation errors).
> - Setting related css classes on the element (ng-valid, ng-invalid,
>     ng-dirty, ng-pristine, ng-touched, ng-untouched, ng-empty,
>     ng-not-empty) including animations.
> - Registering the control with its
>     parent form.

By the way `ng-` prefixed directive don't need `{{ }}`. 
For example you should't write

`required="{{queObj._required}}"` but `required="queObj._required"`

Here's a working `plunker` for text-control-dir

https://plnkr.co/edit/wDPtvj29pt0E6Y7QC0j0?p=preview

Comment: How to move <span ng-show=... inside directive to manage look and feel of UI.

Comment: want to show error msg below input box and from control with red borders.

Comment: @pandudas working plunker with validation messages inside directive
https://plnkr.co/edit/cqg0rL0GPcXI4IsaAaWG?p=preview

Comment: thanks. I did similar changes for select control, and all is working, but if selected value is empty or -1, both should show error.

Comment: What is this textControlForm, will this function work for all control like select and radio.

Comment: @pandudas its just a sub-form name. It should be unique name, otherwise it will be overwritten. 
Actually it should look like this https://plnkr.co/edit/IULVjILwdi5ITn2QXJjN?p=preview

Look at the `form model`, each sub-form (nested form) got their own objects. If any sub-form is invalid than overall form is invalid.

Comment: In above plunker validation not working. for select control i want to add validation when empty or -1 should give error "field required."

Comment: template: '<div class="form-group">\n\
<label for="{{queObj._attributeName}}" class="col-sm-5 control-label">{{queObj._text}}</label>\n\
<div class="col-sm-6"><select ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="queObj._required" class="form-control {{queObj._pageAttributes.cssclass}}" name={{queObj._attributeName}}" id="{{queObj._attributeName}}" >\n\
<option ng-repeat="ans in queObj._answerOptions" value="{{ans._value}}">{{ans._promptText}}</option></select></div>\n\
</div>'

Comment: but validation not working, Added if (form.$valid){... } in autoQuoteCtrl.js. it gives false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118304/discussion-between-pandu-das-and-krutkowski86).

Comment: I am still stuck to create dynamic directive on class/attribute on a directive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821980/how-to-write-directive-on-class-in-angular-js