# How to write directive on class in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The restrict option is typically set to:

'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name
'M' - only matches comment

'C' - only matches class name is not working

`Class="form-control **valid-vehicleyear** ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched"`

I created a directive on class associated with element. On change of value i want to call a api and change value of other element. But no change is observed on change.

controlDirective.js

```
  function validVehicleyear($scope, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',                
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                element.bind('change', function () {
                    console.log('here in validVehicleyear');
                    $http.get('api.php'+scope.ngModel)
                            .then(function (response) {
                                $scope.answers.VehicleMake = response.data;
                            });
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Vehicle year question has a class valid-vehicleyear. what I am missing here, or is there any other to this on change of answers.vehicleyear.
I wrote a directive validVehicleyear on class at Vehicle year question, this i want to call on change of year and set new options for Vehicle make, but it not working.

[plnkr.co/edit/BFGXr7LNAe0KvQipj9JJ?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFGXr7LNAe0KvQipj9JJ?p=preview)

I checked around and found that outer/inner directive concept can work here. but not getting how to apply for the dynamic classes.

Answer (score 7):

Back from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787704/angular-js-onchange-in-directive-at-class-attribute-is-not-working), I tried a couple of things none of which worked for this reason:

You pass a directive as a class but dynamically by interpolation which in itself is bad practice (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues). The class name is interpolated and the element rendered but the directive is not compiled during interpolation.

The only thing that worked was to pass the directive name in clear:

```
class="form-control valid-vehicleyear"
```

But then all your select elements will have this class/directive.

You're trying to automate everything and you're pushing the concept to the extreme which makes your code very unreadable and apparently impossible to debug.

There's nothing wrong with building a form element by element and putting custom directives on each of them for better control.

However there is everything wrong with passing dynamic directives as classes from a JSON object.

Just build your form normally. It won't be less cool or less readable and it will follow best practice (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#restrict-to-elements-and-attributes)

```
<select valid-vehicleyear>
<select valid-makemodel>
...
```

Comment: $compile can be helpfull to create dynamic directive. can you help me with $compile

Answer (score 3):

Some issues in your code:

- Isn't necessary use `scope: { ngModel: '='}`. Instead use `require`.
- For access to the value of the ngModel value passed like 4th argument, use `ngModel.$viewValue`.
- If you need access to the variable of your controller, you have 2 posibilities.

  1. remove the `scope` property for get a **shared scope** with the controller, and access directly to the `answers` variable through the `scope` passed in the link function like this `scope.answers`.
  2. This it's the better option. sharing access to the `answers` variables within the isolated scope property of your directive. `scope: { answers: '=' }`

The modified code:

```
function validVehicleyear($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.bind('change', function () {
          console.log('here in validVehicleyear');
          $http.get('api.php' + ngModel.$viewValue)
            .then(function (response) {
              scope.answers.VehicleMake = response.data;
            });
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

My final recommendation it's not use the Class option, in your case, it's better use the Attribute option.
Good luck!

Comment: There are so many questiuons, all for question are in Ca.json. Here you can see in my plunker,On attribute name I created form element. I am not able to add new attribute to element in directive. but I can pass class that will be added in class="*". So I am using classes for here to achieve things.

Comment: I tried with your code but no change. If I skip classes then how can I create a new dynamic attribute. Each form question should have unique attribute. So that I could apply validation or any change event on specific element only.

Comment: Create a more reduced example with the controllers,services and directives involved.
The approach of my post it's foment good practices. Because the app posted for you in your fiddle it's too large, is difficult for me understand your problem. (many factors could be involved).

Comment: $compile can be helpfull to create dynamic directive. can you help me with $compile