# Placing custom directive in Angular 1.5.8 using ng-repeat is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am placing my custom-directive on the fly in my HTML using ng-repat directive.

But the custom-directives are not evaluated and if the placed the same directive on HTML directly then it is working.

```
...
    <body ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
      <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <div>This is a Problem</div>
    <!--Here in for loop i want to us the value to call a directive-->

    <div ng-repeat="var in arr">

      <!--Here i am using directive with restrict: 'C' and this is not expending-->
      <span class="{{var}}"></span>
    </div>


    <!-- here my directive named "direct" is working fine -->
      <span class="direct"></span>

    </div>
    </body>
...
```

and My Js code is

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = ['direct','indirect']; 
  }]).directive('direct', function() {
    return {
      template: 'direct',
       restrict: 'C'
    };
  }).directive('indirect', function() {
    return {
      template: 'indirect',
      restrict: 'C'
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

I believe there is some compilation issue and i searched web and found $compile  can solve my purpose but unable to implement.

Please help me in solving my issue.

Plunker implemention for same :  https://plnkr.co/edit/lYGg0UkQpNhN5NJx13Zj?p=preview

Comment: It isn't working because when Angular parser comes to `<span class="{{var}}"></span>` it compile DOM & value evaluate `{{var}}` value, that mean `class` attribute value is getting filled up after DOM compilation, that's why directive isn't getting compiled. You could solve this issue by using `ng-switch`/`ng-if` directive, by putting both directive `direct` & indeirect with some `expression` in `ng-if`/`ng-switch`..

Answer (score 0):

Using a directive as a class is bad practice (because unreadable)
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#restrict-to-elements-and-attributes

Then you pass a directive as a class but dynamically by interpolation which in itself is bad practice (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues). The class name is interpolated and the element rendered but the directive is not compiled during interpolation.

Remove the restrict lines from your directive definitions and use them as attributes:

```
<span indirect></span>
```

Then to use them in the ng-repeat loop, you can check if var = "direct" or "indirect"

https://plnkr.co/edit/JUNFMCZASMntCnC6FsIO?p=preview

Comment: ng-switch will not solve my problem because in actual i have to iterate over a JSON and that has a large no. of values in it. I have thought of directive to get rid of ng-switch as of now i have implemented ng-swich and ng-include directives to solve my purpose.

Comment: @Shashank.gupta40 same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821980/how-to-write-directive-on-class-in-angular-js It's not possible. Look into $compile in case but you're better off rethinking what you are building.

Answer (score 0):

Use the directive like this

`<div ng-repeat="var in arr">
     <span direct ng-if="var == 'direct'"><span>
     <span indirect ng-if="var == 'indirect'"><span>
 <div>`

and in controller define restrict as attribute.

`.directive('direct', function() {
    return {
      template: 'direct',
       restrict: 'A'
    };`